# Entity Framework Core - Generic Set method with reflection

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, reflection, entity-framework-core

I have this line of code:

```
dbContext.Set<????>().Add(this.arr);
```

I also have a Type variable. It it possible to put this type variable in `Set<Here>`? If so, how can I achieve this?

What I'm trying to do: Add this.arr object to a dbcontext list. And the type of the list, is given via parameters. That type should be used to decide the generic value of the list.

Comment: What are you just trying to do here, please be specific. The answer will lead to an appropriate solution for core

Comment: What is the type of `this.arr`? EFC has no non generic `DbSet`, in general you just use the non generic `DbContext` methods like `Add`, `AddRange` etc. receiving `object` instances or `object` enumerables/arrays.